# How to add an example for []map[string]string

Tags: go

I used the https://github.com/swaggo/swag library to automatically generate the api document. I have a data type of []map[string]string, how should I add an example?

I checked the doc ,but now show about type []map[string]string.
the docs sites: https://github.com/swaggo/swag

```golang
type UploadReq struct {
    FilesM   []map[string]string `form:"files" json:"files" binding:"required" example:"TODO"`
    Tag      string              `form:"tag" json:"tag" binding:"required" example:"TestTag"` 
    IsPublic bool                `form:"is_public" json:"is_pub" binding:"required" example:"true" `
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The current version of [swag](https://github.com/swaggo/swag) doesn't support examples for map variable type according to the [parser](https://github.com/swaggo/swag/blob/266aebcda91591bae22ba0efe7f4c919434a88b3/parser.go#L1006-L1039)